# PyCharm (JetBrains): How do I Prevent "Usage in ___" In Search Results?

Tags: pycharm

Back in the 3.x version of PyCharm if I did a "Find in Path" (ie. a global text search, ie. a "grep") all of the results for a given file would come back together.  After upgrading to the 4.x version of PyCharm I now find my results from the same file inexplicably separated from each other.

In other words, if I have:

```
define([
    'foo'
], function(
    foo
) {
```

and I do a search for "foo", I get back the second occurrence (`foo`) first, and then after all other occurrences of "foo" are found in other files I finally see the first occurrence (`'foo'`) listed under "Usage in string constants".

This is really annoying, so my question is: does anyone know how I can disable this feature?  I've looked through all of the "Find in Path" options and searched through the settings, but I can't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

Man, I looked everywhere except the one spot that mattered: the results pane itself.  It turns out there's an icon ([image: Group by Usage Type]) which you can click to turn this feature off.

I guess I'll leave this question/answer though just in case someone else has the same question I did.